# Is self executing function considered a good practice in nodejs module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know that, having self executing function, is a good practice for JavaScript in browser, to avoid variable scoping issue.

However, I was wondering, is self executing function still required, in nodejs module? Or, it is no longer serve the variable scoping purpose?

For instance

### screenshot.js (Without self executing function)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
module.exports = async (url, width, height, path) => {
  ...
  return screenshot;
};
```

### screenshot.js (With self executing function)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(function () {
  module.exports = async (url, width, height, path) => {
    ...
    return screenshot;
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular self executing function expression that you show in your second code block serves no purpose in a node.js module because a node.js module is already wrapped (by node.js) into it's own function, so it already has it's own unique function scope.  There is no need to wrap it again to give it another unique function scope.

You can see the actual node.js module wrapper [here in the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper).

```
(function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
    // Module code actually lives in here
});
```

This wrapper function is what is executed when your module runs and your modules code is inserted into this wrapper before the code is handed to `eval()` to parse.